# opening an image in native android gallery app

Tags: android, file, android-intent, uri

i have an application that saves an image (jpeg) onto the sd card. i can view the file by manually starting gallery. however i want to programmaticly start gallery and view the file when the file is saved. 
--i have the absolute path of the file.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent ();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    intent.setData(uri);
    sendBroadcast (intent);
```

it doesn't cause any errors, but nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Not:

```
startBroadcast(intent);
```

So your code should look like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent ();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent)
```

Additionally you might consider doing the following:

```
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
```

instead of

```
intent.setData(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
// Show only images, no videos or anything else
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

ref-http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-pick-image-from-gallery/